# How to go back to previous version in git

Tags: git

I have a checkout copy of a remote git repository in my workstation.
I have accidentally committed a change in my local and pushed to remote.
Now I want to remove the last commit and go back to the previous commit and the same should be pushed to remote.

I am okay if it is a new commit with a commit message. How to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd advise against pushing with --force an alternative history.
Anyone who already pulled your changes will have a completely screwed history to deal with when pulling new stuff.

A far safer option is to simply do

```
git revert HEAD~1 
git push origin master
```

[git revert](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) will record a new commit that cancels all of the effects of the previous one

Comment: What does `error: your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge` mean?  Isn't that the whole point?  That I want to discard my latest commit and go back to the one previous?

Comment: That means that you probably still have changes that are not committed. This is about having a clean index (local state) and just reverting the last committed changes.

Answer (score 11):

If nobody has yet cloned your updated remote repo, you can:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
git push --force
```

That will force the local and remote history to discard the latest commit.
(Check first with a git fetch that no new commits had been pushed since your incorrect commit)

If a new history isn't an option, then a **[`git revert`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html)** is more secure, and will result in a new commit canceling the previous one: you can then push that new commit.