# Visual Studio - How to track project versions

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple question: how do you track the project versions when you are working on a project that you need to make changes from time to time? And some times the changes were wrong, so we maybe need to revert to the previous version.

If I understand correctly, the Visual Studio does offer methods to track version changes, however, when TFVC requires a Team Server, Git also more like a Tack Changes used between multiple developers.

For now, I'm just making a copy of the whole project folder every time I accomplished something or when I decide to make some "huge" changes.

Is there a better method? Or Git is the answer?

PS: I'm the only one on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, especially with the Git integration in 2013 (even for visual Studio 2012 update 3: "Visual Studio Tools for Git"), Git would allow you to:

- avoid copying your project for each new modification: simply commit and push each new stable revision of your project, while keeping in the same working tree.
- [revert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992711/6309) easily a previous commit you want to cancel/fix (or, since you are the only one on your project; even [force a push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897699/6309)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I haven't got time to try it yet, but it should be the one.